# Best online source for spices

Tags: spices, shopping

I'm looking or good online sources for spices.  Good selection and good prices.

Comment: I came across an older meta question about the fate of this question. It didn't get that many votes, but the ones it did were in favor of closing (without deleting). http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/1977/should-this-old-question-be-kept/1979#1979

Answer (score 7):

Penzey's spices is one of the most well known places for spices:

http://www.penzeys.com/

They have an extensive selection and reasonable prices.

Comment: Penzey's for me too - recommended to me by my "food guru".

Comment: Friend recommended Penzeys a while back, I won't shop anywhere else online for spices since.

Answer (score 3):

I buy pretty much all of my spices from The Spice House at http://www.thespicehouse.com/. I particularly like their salt-free blends since I have high blood pressure. They also have more varieties of paprika than most similar stores and they have a "vanilla paste" that gives vanilla bean like results, but much cheaper than whole beans.

Answer (score 2):

I've been trying to find a source for cardamom in bulk and I stumbled on the SpiceJungle. I love their website! Their prices are even better. You might want to give then a try: https://www.spicejungle.com